# Как стереть введенное число в консольном приложении?

Tags: c++, cin

Хочу спросить вот к примеру я сделал так чтобы пользователь в консольном приложении вводил число и это число становилось значением переменной, и мне надо сделать так чтобы то что он ввел либо очистилось, или скрылось c строки, но чтобы еще значение переменной сохранилось. Ввод выполняется с помощью оператора cin.

Comment: проблема в том, что когда пользователь нажимает enter то происходит перевод на новую строку, а после этого уже ничего нельзя поделать

Comment: если операционная система - windows, можно с помощью winapi. если приложение просто для баловства - `system("cls")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить положение курсора и заполнить место пробелами например.

Borland C++

```
#include <conio.h>
void gotoxy(int x,int y);
```

VS

```
#include <windows.h>
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
```

Comment: а что делать с данной функцией? Ввести после оператора cin?

Comment: Да, вы ее прописываете, затем вызываете. Она изменяет положение курсора, а затем вы используете cout и заполняете пробелами